# What is the regex ValidationExpression to allow only numbers 1 to 100 in text box?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I would like to limit my users input in text box to allow only positive numbers from 1 to 100 how can I do this using a regex expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the string is 100 or two digits:

```
^100$|^[0-9]?[0-9]$
```

Comment: Great thanks! Am I able to use the "|" (or) function for any validation expression? This would be useful for another ValidationExpression I want to use.

Comment: also how do I use the dollar symbol inside one of these expressions without closing the validation?